# How to get data that was createdAt or updatedAt 30 seconds from the the current time PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, elasticsearch, node-postgres

I'm trying to access data from a table that was created or updated data 30 seconds from the current time. Does anyone have any good idea of how to do this efficiently? I'm using node.js and pg package in npm. I want to grab the newly created/updated data to sync with elasticsearch.

Comment: Do you have a `timestamp` column that stores the time of creation of  a row?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have columns with createdAt and UpdatedAt, How ever i'm not sure how to get the rows created at 30 seconds ago from the time right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rows that were created **exactly** 30 seconds ago:

```
select *
from the_table
where createdat = current_timestamp - interval '30' second
```

The rows that were created between 30 seconds ago and now:

```
select *
from the_table
where createdat >= current_timestamp - interval '30' second
```

Comment: Whats the difference between both of them? Aren't they doing the same thing?

Comment: @jamestwiggle: look carefully `=` vs. `>=`